# nextflow error cause: Unexpected character: '"' @ line 27, column 27. value = "${baseDir}/db/$value"

Tags: nextflow

```
process refs {
    output:
    path "fa", emit: fa
    path "sdf", emit: sdf
    path "chrsize", emit: chrsize
    path "non", emit: non
    path "dbsnp", emit:dbsnp
    path "pvcf", emit: pvcf
    
    script:
    def dblist = file("$baseDir/db/db.list")
    dblist.text.eachline {line ->
        def tokens = line.trim().split(/\s+/)
        def (key, value) = tokens
        def (ref1, suf) = key.split(".")
        if (ref1 == params.ref) {
            value = "$baseDir/db/$value"
            "echo $value > $suf"
        }
    } 

}
workflow {
    refs().out.fa.view()
}
```

db.list looks like this:

```
hg38.fa    path1
hg38.sdf   path2
hg38.snp   path3
...
hg19.fa    pathx
hg19.sdf   pathy
...
```

params.ref is hg19 or hg38. I got the error message in the title. Why I got an error in line value = "${baseDir}/db/$value" or do you have some other ways to write this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I can see what you're trying to do here. The problem is that, unless you're willing to localize *all* the files in the *db.list*, the files you're trying to select for won't be available inside the working directory. A better way would be to use a Map param to include the paths to the reference files, similar to how the [nf-core](https://nf-co.re/) defines their [genomes](https://github.com/nf-core/rnaseq/blob/3.11.1/conf/igenomes.config) param:

> ```
> params {
>     // illumina iGenomes reference file paths
>     genomes {
>         'GRCh37' {
>             fasta       = "${params.igenomes_base}/Homo_sapiens/Ensembl/GRCh37/Sequence/WholeGenomeFasta/genome.fa"
>             bwa         = "${params.igenomes_base}/Homo_sapiens/Ensembl/GRCh37/Sequence/BWAIndex/version0.6.0/"
>             bowtie2     = "${params.igenomes_base}/Homo_sapiens/Ensembl/GRCh37/Sequence/Bowtie2Index/"
>             star        = "${params.igenomes_base}/Homo_sapiens/Ensembl/GRCh37/Sequence/STARIndex/"
>             bismark     = "${params.igenomes_base}/Homo_sapiens/Ensembl/GRCh37/Sequence/BismarkIndex/"
>             gtf         = "${params.igenomes_base}/Homo_sapiens/Ensembl/GRCh37/Annotation/Genes/genes.gtf"
>             bed12       = "${params.igenomes_base}/Homo_sapiens/Ensembl/GRCh37/Annotation/Genes/genes.bed"
>             readme      = "${params.igenomes_base}/Homo_sapiens/Ensembl/GRCh37/Annotation/README.txt"
>             mito_name   = "MT"
>             macs_gsize  = "2.7e9"
>             blacklist   = "${projectDir}/assets/blacklists/GRCh37-blacklist.bed"
>         }
>         'GRCh38' {
>             fasta       = "${params.igenomes_base}/Homo_sapiens/NCBI/GRCh38/Sequence/WholeGenomeFasta/genome.fa"
>             bwa         = "${params.igenomes_base}/Homo_sapiens/NCBI/GRCh38/Sequence/BWAIndex/version0.6.0/"
>             bowtie2     = "${params.igenomes_base}/Homo_sapiens/NCBI/GRCh38/Sequence/Bowtie2Index/"
>             star        = "${params.igenomes_base}/Homo_sapiens/NCBI/GRCh38/Sequence/STARIndex/"
>             bismark     = "${params.igenomes_base}/Homo_sapiens/NCBI/GRCh38/Sequence/BismarkIndex/"
>             gtf         = "${params.igenomes_base}/Homo_sapiens/NCBI/GRCh38/Annotation/Genes/genes.gtf"
>             bed12       = "${params.igenomes_base}/Homo_sapiens/NCBI/GRCh38/Annotation/Genes/genes.bed"
>             mito_name   = "chrM"
>             macs_gsize  = "2.7e9"
>             blacklist   = "${projectDir}/assets/blacklists/hg38-blacklist.bed"
>         }
>         ...
> ```

This would then let you access each of the required files using your `params.ref` as the key. The nf-core wraps this logic in a function<sup>[1](https://github.com/nf-core/rnaseq/blob/3.11.1/lib/WorkflowMain.groovy#L91-L101)</sup>:

> ```
> //
> // Get attribute from genome config file e.g. fasta
> //
> public static Object getGenomeAttribute(params, attribute) {
>     if (params.genomes && params.genome && params.genomes.containsKey(params.genome)) {
>         if (params.genomes[ params.genome ].containsKey(attribute)) {
>             return params.genomes[ params.genome ][ attribute ]
>         }
>     }
>     return null
> }
> ```